# Registering for recurring event shows wrong date on confirmation screen

Tags: civievent, online-registration

We have a series of classes that were created with recurring events.  Users can sign up for some or all of the classes in the series.  If a user attempts to register for a class, the confirmation screen will show the dates of the first class in the series, not the one that the user was registering for.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi M. Welcome. It is always worth mentioning your version of CiviCRM, whether or not you have been able to replicate the issue on the demo site eg http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/, and for some questions, the CMS in use

Comment: Thank you for that. I am currently running CiviCRM 4.7.15 on Wordpress.  On my site if I try to register using the Event Links it works well and shows the correct date (same on the demo) however if I create a WP page and put the online registration shortcode on the page, then on the confirmation screen it shows the date of the first event of the series.  I'm not sure how to test that on the demo if it is even possible.  Appreciate any insights into this issue.